# Trimble pathfinder data dictionary default value exclusion

Tags: data, gps, trimble, dictionary, pathfinder

Is it possible to have a numeric attribute in trimble pathfinder without having to use a default value? I am trying to make a numeric attribute compulsory to fill in BUT because the data dictionary editor forces the use of a default value such as zero, the software automatically treats the attribute as being logged instead of alerting the field capturer if he or she has missed a field if they accidentally do not answer the question in the field.

This means that setting a numeric attribute to "required" doesn't mean anything in the field because if the value is not filled in it just accepts the default as a field entry anyway.

Comment: There is an option in the Data Dictionary Editor to make field entry required.  I believe that means the feature can't be close until a particular field has be entered.